# How do I Fix: ImportError: cannot import name 'app_commands' from partially initialized module 'discord'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2.1.0 version of ds (It should have app_commands)

```
from discord import app_commands, Intents, Client, Interaction
 
 
class Bot(Client):
    def __init__(self, *, intents: Intents):
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
        self.tree = app_commands.CommandTree(self)
 
    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        await self.tree.sync(guild=None)
 
 
bot = Bot(intents=Intents.default())
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Conectado como: {bot.user}")
 
@bot.tree.command()
async def givemebadge(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Listo!, espera 24 horas para reclamar la insignia\nPuedes reclamarla aquí: https://discord.com/developers/active-developer")
 
 
bot.run("TokenHere")
```

```
File "c:\Users\name\python\discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    from discord import app_commands, Intents, Client, Interaction
  File "c:\Users\name\python\discord.py", line 1, in <module>
    from discord import app_commands, Intents, Client, Interaction
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_commands' from partially initialized module 'discord' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\name\python\discord.py)
```

Comment: By naming your module `discord.py` you're trying to import your own file, not the `discord` package. Change your file name.

Comment: if this solved your problem, close the question and let us know